# Permittivity. What does it permit?

Tags: electromagnetism

From the name of the concept, you would expect the permittivity of a medium to be the ability of the medium to permit something.

One may expect that, permittivity would be the ability of the medium to permit electrical fields through it. However, looking at Coulombs law and its derivatives,
$$
E = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon} \frac{Q}{r^2}
$$
one can tell that a high permittivity means a low electrical intensity (i.e., the electrical field not being permitted through) and viceversa. So it seems that in this scenario, should be named impermittivity

Therefore, what does the permittivity of a medium permit?

Comment: For consistency, I think we should refer to the Coulomb constant $k$ as the forbidittivity of free space.

Comment: Words introduced by Oliver Heavisde: impedance, inductance, permeability, permittance, permittivity, reluctance....  He had lots of terms he  needed a word for. Why he picked the ones he did is not really answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permittivity of a medium is the ability of the medium to permit polarization of itself under the effect of a electric field.

When a medium is polarized due to such an electric field, another electric field is induced, where the field lines are opposite of the original one. As a result, the total electric field inside of the medium is diminished.

Answer (score 6):

It permits the electric field to do something with the matter/medium. Forget the Coulomb’s force law for a moment, and consider the Gauss’ law. It states the following:

$$Q\propto\int_{\partial V}E\cdot\mathrm{d}s$$

where $Q$ is the total electric charge of the matter in the volume $V$, and $E$ the electric field. Now here the proportional constant is the permittivity of matter, denoted by $\varepsilon$, which is about how much the matter is permitting the electric field to do something effective with the matter.

Here, the word “permit” doesn’t mean how well the matter is permitting the field to exist throughout the volume, but how well the matter permits the field to itself.

For instance, if the matter is not permitting the field at all to itself, this would mean letting the field going through the matter with no interruption (i.e., vacuum, lowest possible permittivity). But if the matter is permitting the field to do something effective with the matter, then the field will lose some of its magnitude which results in lower flux at the boundary.

Comment: But won't you have the same problem? Gauss' law says that $\phi_E = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon}$ so a high permittivity implies a low flux, i.e., the electric flux isn't permitted through.

Comment: @mendus Yes, but that argument only applies for a positive charge. If the charge is negative, then higher permittivity implies higher flux. This isn’t very consistent. But I get your point - what you’re trying to describe is that higher permittivity doesn’t mean, per se, better preservation of the field strength throughout the space, but rather the opposite.

Comment: @mendus, do you discovered the correct answer for your question? I'm interested in this answer. No one has ever given me a satisfactory answer for your question.

Comment: @GuilhermeCorreaTeixeira I added an answer to the question, see if it is satisfactory to you.

Answer (score 0):

[Consider a differential forms approach](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1668&context=facpub). E is the electric field intensity. It is a one-form represented by parallel planes that are more densely spaced at higher intensities. D is the electric flux density. It is a two-form represented by tubes that pierce the surfaces. These tubes are more densely compacted for larger D.

$D= \epsilon \star E$

$\epsilon$ depends on the medium.

$\star$ depends on the metric.

Maxwell's Equations relate $E,B,H,$ and $D$. $E$ and $D$ are not the same. This is usually glossed over in introductory textbooks, but when  experiments were done that verified Maxwell's equations they needed to keep track of this difference. The equations relate field intensities to a flux densities. And simplifying units obscure that.

Answer (score 0):

In the view of Faraday - and later Maxwell - all of space is a plenum that functions as a polarizable medium and contains a large amount of energy. Maxwell asserted (in "Note on the Attraction of Gravitation", article 82 in his 1864 "A Dynamical Theory of the Electromagnetic Field") that the density of energy exceeds the density corresponding to the maximum possible gravitational potential in the universe.

The electric field $$ at a given point determines how much force a unit charge at that point will experience. The electric displacement $$ determines how much the space at that point is polarized: the density of charge displacement.

The permittivity determines how much displacement $$ occurs per unit of electric field $$. It determines how much the space polarizes, for a given electric field.

**Edit:**
The Wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity

says "It is a measure of how dense of an electric field is "permitted" to form in response to electric charges"

which sort of speaks to the reciprocal relation. Maxwell, in the 1864 reference, actually used the reciprocal of permittivity as the coefficient, rather than permittivity itself, calling it $k$.

Using $Q, L, M, T$, respectively to denote the dimensions of charge, length, mass and time, the dimension of force is $ML/T^2$, of charge $Q$, of charge-separation $QL$, and the density thereof: $QL/L^3 = Q/L^2$. Therefore, the dimensions of $$ and $$ are, respectively, $ML/(QT^2)$ and $Q/L^2$.

If you define the dimension conjugate to $Q$ as $P$ - i.e. the dimension which, when combined with $Q$ gives you the dimension of action $ML^2/T$, then the dimension of $$ can just as well be written as $P/(LT)$. The respective units for $Q$ and $P$ are Coulomb and Weber; and the unit for permittivity will then be $(Q/L^2)/(P/(LT))$ or $QT/(PL)$.

A similar consideration applies to the magnetic field $$ and magnetic induction $$ ... something that Maxwell was slow on the uptake in distinguishing and which he hadn't yet clearly distinguished between by 1864, but only later in the 1870's in the treatise. There, the respective dimensions are $ML/(PT^2) = Q/(LT)$ for $$, and $P/L^2$ for $$. The corresponding response coefficient - the permeability - then has the dimension $PT/(QL)$. The dimension of electric and magnetic charge are conjugate, so $P$ is also the dimension of magnetic charge.

Maxwell had an extra $4π$ with those quantities, so his $$ is our $4π$ and his permittivity $μ$ is our $μ/(4π)$. So, the units used today are calibrated with an extra $4π$, relative to our $μ$, so that a Henry (the unit for the dimension of inductance, $PT/Q$) is set to $μ_0/(4π)$ multiplied by 10000 km - the route distance between the equator and north or south pole (as per the standard of the time), where $μ_0$ is the permeability of the vacuum. Currently, the meter is calibrated to $c/299792458$ seconds, where $c$ is the speed of electromagnetic waves in a vacuum and 1 km is 1000 meters. Finally, the permeability of the vacuum $ε_0 = 1/(c^2 μ_0)$, since the wave speed in the vacuum is $c = 1/\sqrt{ε_0 μ_0}$. This reduces all the units for all the combinations of $L$, $T$ and $Q$ (and $P$) to combinations of $c$, $μ_0$ and the second.

**Edit:**
Actually, as I just noticed: that changed a short while ago in 2019. So, now the fundamental charge $e$ is used in place of vacuum permittivity $μ_0$ as a fundamental constant, and Planck's constant $h$ is used to clamp down on a precise definition of the mass unit "kilogram". That means $μ_0$ is no longer precisely $4π×10^{-7}$ Henry/meter in SI units, now that the units have been redefined, but only approximately so.